# log4j with spring doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, maven

In my pom.xml, I've added a dependency for using Log4j

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I executed the following command

```
mvn clean install
```

After this command, I notice that the log4j-1.2.9.jar is well added in my lib directory itself in the target directory

Then, I started the google app engine server with the following command in my project :

```
appengine:devserver
```

And my log4j.properties in src/main/resources

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

After, by opening the jar file in winzip, I noticed that the Logger.class was in org/apache/log4j directory, so, when I tried to import the Logger class in a java file, it didn't detect the package 'log4j'.

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Comment: In your build tag, do you have any resources defined? Also, if I'm not mistaken, Spring uses log4j too so you probably have 2 log4j in your classpath, the one defined and another one as a transitive Spring dependency. That's easy to check : mvn dependency:tree.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Spring uses `commons-logging` without any logging subsytem dependency specified. Also Maven's dependency resolution should prevent having the same library with two different versions on class-path (unless their groupId or articactId is different - and `log4j` does not have any alternative names).

Comment: What does it mean *"it didn't detect the package 'log4j'"*? You mean that you had problems with your IDE's autocomplete or you have `ClassNotFoundException` when running the application? And when and why does WinZIP come in play?